# Parent div won't resize height to contain children [CSS]

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my parent div expand as I add more children, but both setting the height of the parent to auto (or not declaring a height at all) gives itself a total random height not equal to any, or sum of any, children. inspecting the element doesn't show where the height is coming from either. This is the parent's CSS

```
.main-container{
    justify-content: center;
    background-color:rgb(255, 40, 40);
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Please could you put up a snippet with some children which shows the problem. As it stands there is not enough info for us to find out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

add these two lines to the parents css

```
.main-container { 
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```